# Captive portal - Apple devices not getting automatic browser popup

Tags: ios, macos, wifi, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I have created a custom captive portal (externally hosted, made with PHP) on Ubiquity Unifi infrastructure. Everything works fine, except:

**Apple devices (OSX, iOS) don't get the usual popup with the captive portal upon connection.**

My employer requires this to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using and internally hosted controller or cloud controller ? what environment ? linux? Windows? Version?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question based on: https://serverfault.com/questions/679393/captive-portal-popups-the-definitive-guide

iOS and OSX devices make a request to a URL to detect captive portals. The rules are the following:

> 1. GET/POST http://foo.com/bar.html
> 2. If bar.html == [expected content] > Open Internet
> 3. If bar.html != [expected content] > Captive Portal
> 4. If bar.html[status] != SUCCESS > No Network

However, I was redirecting users using an HTTP header when they first hit the captive portal. This does not fall into any of the above rules and therefore prevented Apple devices from detecting that there was a captive portal.

Here is my final code, which redirects to my portal from a weird URL that the hotspot gives:

```
<?php
/* Trying to get Apple to show the WiFi popup */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['url']) && (strstr($_REQUEST['url'],'success.html') || strstr($_REQUEST['url'],'detect.html'))) {
    echo '
    Redirecting...
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "/index.html";
    </script>';
    exit;
}

header("Location:/index.html?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

As you can see, Apple devices need to see some actual content, not a redirect.

I also rewrite the .php file extensions as .html.

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: `If bar.html != [expected content] > Captive Portal`: what expected content should be? What content must be defined in order to make a Mobile Device with iOS, to recognize a Captive Portal? It seems a little bit vague for me... I was wondering here if maybe, iOS could work just like Android, expecting a `204` from a URL..

Comment: @ivanleoncz have you tried this? Seems like Apple requires some content (doesn't matter what) just not a redirect with no body. I'll try this since I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No @SandroAntonucci, I didn't. Actually, I'm working on a project for a CaptivePortal written in Python, as a guard for Squid. I'm just getting started, but you can follow the progress, and probably, I'll create some approach, considering this topic. https://github.com/ivanlmj/PyCaptive

Comment: I can confirm this works, also for iOS 7 I tested it checks for a random URL in captive.apple.com, you can just do a 302 rewrite with your webserver that redirects every request with that host to the same page seamlessy. iOS 10 checks hotspot-detect.html

Comment: I'm using iptables to intercept and redirect packets to the webserver's ip address and it's not working. It works on android, linux, and windows. Have not tested other mobile OS but certainly doesn't work with ios.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this issue can also happen if in the advanced network configuration you have configured a custom DNS IP address.

Check and to fix, simply go to

System Preferences -> Network -> WiFi -> Advanced… -> DNS

and see if there are only IPs that are greyed out (good) or if you have IPs in normal (bright) letters (bad)

If you find custom configured IPs, just click on each and the “-“ button at the bottom left of the window.